# PHP CSV MySql Import

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following issue that I hope ya'll can shed some light on. I am trying to import a csv that although it looks normal (, for seperators) yet when I attempt to import there is always a line break after the 40th ish column.

This is my code for the import:

```
<?php
// include mysql database configuration file
require_once "layouts/config.php";
 
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 
            // Open uploaded CSV file with read-only mode
            $csvFile = fopen(__DIR__. '/uploads/upload.csv', 'r');
            //fgetcsv($csvFile);
            $values = array();
            while (($getData = fgetcsv($csvFile, 300, ",")) !== FALSE)
            {
               $values[]= "('".$getData[0]."' , '".$getData[1]."' ,'".$getData[2]."' ,'".$getData[3]."' ,'".$getData[4]."' ,
                            '".$getData[5]."' , '".$getData[6]."' ,'".$getData[7]."' ,'".$getData[8]."' ,'".$getData[9]."' ,
                            '".$getData[10]."', '".$getData[11]."','".$getData[12]."','".$getData[13]."','".$getData[14]."',
                            '".$getData[15]."', '".$getData[16]."','".$getData[17]."','".$getData[18]."','".$getData[19]."',
                            '".$getData[20]."', '".$getData[21]."','".$getData[22]."','".$getData[23]."','".$getData[24]."',
                            '".$getData[25]."', '".$getData[26]."','".$getData[27]."','".$getData[28]."','".$getData[29]."',
                            '".$getData[30]."', '".$getData[31]."','".$getData[32]."','".$getData[33]."','".$getData[34]."',
                            '".$getData[35]."', '".$getData[36]."','".$getData[37]."','".$getData[38]."','".$getData[39]."',
                            '".$getData[40]."', '".$getData[41]."','".$getData[42]."','".$getData[43]."','".$getData[44]."',
                            '".$getData[45]."', '".$getData[46]."','".$getData[47]."','".$getData[48]."','".$getData[49]."',
                            '".$getData[50]."', '".$getData[51]."','".$getData[52]."','".$getData[53]."','".$getData[54]."',
                            '".$getData[55]."', '".$getData[56]."','".$getData[57]."')";
            } 
    $sql =  "INSERT INTO machine (PresetNumber, Dates, Starts, Stops, ProductCode, ProductName, Proper, TargetWeight1, Totals, Mean, StandardD, Maxs, Mins, 
            ProductRange, Under, Over, OverScale, ReCheckCnt, TotalNegErr, Preset, TargetWeight2, BagLength, BagWidth, StartIPS, StopIPS, TotalTime, PlannedTime, ITPSDownTime, 
            ITPSOff, LowProductTime, DownStreamDownTime, OperatingTime,FullProductTime,GoodBagMakingTime, NetOperatingTime, FacultyBagMakingTime, PlannedShutdown, Speed, 
            ITPSOEE, SystemAvalability, WeigherEfficiency, BagMakerEfficiency,  WeightLossRatio,    ProductWaste,   InputProduct,   OutputProduct,  AverageWeight,  
            StandardDeviation, CombinationCount, FilledBags, GoodBags, GoodProductBags, FilmWaste, InputFilm, OutputFilm, FilmWasteUpstream, FilmWasteMiddle, FilmWasteDownStream) 
            
            VALUES " . implode(',',$values); 
              
            //fclose($csvFile);
            if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) 
            {
            echo "File(s) uploaded successfully!";
            }           
            else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $link->error;
                }  
                 
    
}

''''
```

My CSV File is

```
5,2022/05/17,16:22,11:21,AJ,,112965,39.0 g,4485.5 kg,39.707 g,0.495 g,42.0 g,39.0 g,3.0 g,1035,2218,451,58,0 g,5,39.0g,1.92inch,1.27inch,2022.5.19. 09:52,2022.5.19. 11:01,68min34sec,68min34sec,7min25sec,4min30sec,2min55sec,0min0sec,61min10sec,0min0sec,0min0sec,0min0sec,61min9sec,0,0bpm,0.0%,89.1%,0%,0.0%,0.0%,0.2%,226.3kg,225.8kg,0.000g,0.000g,5811,0,0,0,0.0%,0.00feet,0.00feet,0.0,0.0,0.0
```

Yet for some reason when I import this CSV the line always breaks after the 40th column. Now If I import a CSV with some dummy data (sequential count from 1 to 58) this file will import fine. Im pretty new to this so I am not sure what I am missing.
Thanks Much

Comment: Change the 300 in `fgetcsv` to null as it is probably cutting the lines off.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php: _"length: Must be greater than the longest line (in characters) to be found in the CSV file (allowing for trailing line-end characters). Otherwise the line is split in chunks of length characters, unless the split would occur inside an enclosure."_ - are you sure your 40 columns fit into 300 characters ...?

Comment: Why aren't you using `LOAD DATA INFILE`?